# Show "log-"ticks in the case of small range

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I use the `pgfplots` package.

Is there any solution to show the "log"-ticks when the range of the data are small? One solution consists in increasing manually the range using `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` but it is not very satisfactory.

For instance on the following example, I want to show the ticks for x=1, x=2, x=3. I can do it manually but can I force pgfplots to show it automatically?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[]
      \addplot [smooth,mark=none,line width=2pt] coordinates {(1,10) (2,11) (3,13)};      %
    \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[xmin=1,xmax=10,ymin=1,ymax=100]
      \addplot [smooth,mark=none,line width=2pt] coordinates {(1,10) (2,11) (3,13)};      
    \end{loglogaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not good idea... Let's say you do it in your example for ymax=1000 (x=3 of your phrase before the MWE)... Do you like it? So we (and pgf) need much more info about when and how many digits have to be plotted... (May be you mean to take the minimum and maximum integer needed... But then are you going to plot only with coordinates? or other ways too?)

Comment: In fact my example was wrong due to the use of x=0. I correct it.

Comment: The only thing I need is to use log scale in boths axis and to show ticks of the form y*10^x (x and y must be integers and y is positive). In my example it could be ticks associated to 1, 2 and 3  (1*10^0, 2*10^0, 3*10^0).

Comment: pgflots removes the log axis in the first example and use a linear scale